# Emacs server exit when losing connection to Xserver

Tags: server

I run Emacs on development host under X Window as:

```
$ emacs24
```

with `~/.emacs`:

```
(require 'server)
(server-start)
```

Next when I connect to Emacs as:

```
$ ssh -Y localhost
ssh$ emacsclient -c
C-x C-c
ssh$ exit
```

or as:

```
$ startx xterm -- `command -v Xnest` :1 -geometry 800x600
xnest$ emacsclient -c
C-x C-c
xnest$ exit
```

main Emacs exit.

I like ability to join to my Emacs session from remote host for getting working context immediately. But when I come to original host or try to re-establish X connection - I have to start new Emacs.

How to make Emacs live when I close remote X connection?

**UPDATE** I don't try `--daemon`as think that `(server-start)` are equivalent form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I submitted a [bug](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?archive=yes&bug=20263) and got response that this is [known bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85715) of GTK since 2002. See `etc/PROBLEMS`:

```
** When Emacs is compiled with Gtk+, closing a display kills Emacs.
```

As temporary solution - it is recommended to use Lucid Emacs build:

```
$ sudo apt-get install emacs-lucid
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a virtual display solution, such as `xpra`, to retain the X display session of emacs even after disconnecting from the remote server. Then, if you set `DISPLAY` environment to the virtual display of `xpra` when you create the emacs server instance it would keep your emacs session alive across network disconnections as if you are using a local display in the server.

See more details about `xpra` at: http://xpra.org/